# Problems plotting Receiver Operating Characteristic with scikit-learn?

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I would like to plot the Receiver Operating Characteristic curve, so I do the following:

```
from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve, auc
predictions = auto_wclf.predict_proba(X_test)
false_positive_rate, recall, thresholds = roc_curve(y_test, predictions[:, 1])
roc_auc = auc(false_positive_rate, recall)
plt.title('Receiver Operating Characteristic')
plt.plot(false_positive_rate, recall, 'b', label='AUC = %0.2f' % roc_auc)
plt.legend(loc='lower right')
plt.plot([0, 1], [0, 1], 'r--')
plt.xlim([0.0, 1.0])
plt.ylim([0.0, 1.0])
plt.ylabel('Recall')
plt.xlabel('Fall-out')
plt.show()
```

But I get this exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "plot.py", line 172, in <module>
    false_positive_rate, recall, thresholds = roc_curve(y_test, predictions[:, 1])
  File "plot.py", line 890, in roc_curve
    y_true, y_score, pos_label=pos_label, sample_weight=sample_weight)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/metrics.py", line 710, in _binary_clf_curve
    raise ValueError("Data is not binary and pos_label is not specified")
ValueError: Data is not binary and pos_label is not specified
```

I have a multilabel classification problem (5 categories). Any idea of how to plot this?. Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: Does the ROC curve is only for binary classification?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, ROC curve "is a graphical plot that illustrates the performance of a **binary classifier system** as its discrimination threshold is varied"([wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Receiver_operating_characteristic)).

Moreover, "The extension of ROC curves for classification problems with more than two classes has always been cumbersome, as the degrees of freedom increase quadratically with the number of classes, and the ROC space has c(c-1) dimensions, where c is the number of classes."([same wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Receiver_operating_characteristic#ROC_curves_beyond_binary_classification)) Since you have 5 classes and even multilabel, ROC curve isn't suitable for you.

Use metrics like [Hamming loss](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.hamming_loss.html), [F1-score](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.f1_score.html), [accuracy](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.accuracy_score.html#sklearn.metrics.accuracy_score), [precision](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.precision_score.html), [recall](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.recall_score.html#sklearn.metrics.recall_score) instead - choose the most suitable one for your task.